# UNIQUE constraint failed: rango_category.name

Tags: python, django

Hi im following the tango with django tutorial.. I've searched for a solution to this but nothing!

```
the error:
IntegrityError at /rango/add_category/
UNIQUE constraint failed: rango_category.name
```

my model:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Category(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Page(models.Model):

    category = models.ForeignKey(Category) #ForeignKey denotes a relationship between page and category
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    url = models.URLField()
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

my add_category view:

```
def add_category(request):
    # Get the context from the request.
    context = RequestContext(request)


    # A HTTP POST?
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CategoryForm(request.POST)


        #Have we been provided with a valid form?
        if form.is_valid():
            #save the new category to the database
            form.save(commit=True)


            # Now call the index() view.
            # The user will be shown the Homepage.
            return index(request)
        else:
            # The supplied form contained errors - just print them to the terminal
            print (form.errors)
    else:
        form = CategoryForm()


    # Bad form (or form details), no form supplied...
    # Render the form with error message(if any).
    return render_to_response('rango/add_category.html', {'form':form}, context)
```

my forms:

```
from django import forms
from rango.models import Page, Category

class CategoryForm(forms.ModelForm):

    names = forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="please enter the category name.")
    views = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=0)
    likes = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial=0)

        #an inline class to to provide additional information on the form
    class Meta:
            # provide an association between the Modelform and a model
        model = Category
        fields = ('views', 'likes')

class PageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="Please enter the title of the page")
    url = forms.URLField(max_length=200, help_text="Please enter the url of the page")
    views = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(),initial=0)

    class Meta:
            # Provide an association between the ModelForm and a model
        model = Page

            #what fields do we want to include in our form
            # this way we dont need every field in the model present
            # Some fields may allow NULL values, so we may not want to include them...
            # Here we are hiding. 
        fields = ('title', 'url', 'views')
```

Comment: I hope thats clear somewhat..thanks anyone

Comment: Well apparently you create two categories with the same name. But your `unique=True` constraint prevents that.

Comment: Hey willem Van Onsem.. bear with me what two categories?

Comment: I made sure categories added were unique...

Answer (score 0):

'name' field is missing in CategoryForm's Meta 'fields'. Since Category::name is a unique field and default is not possible, any attempt to save will fail.

> If the model does not allow the missing fields to be empty, and does
>   not provide a default value (not possible for unique) for the missing fields, any attempt to save() a ModelForm with missing fields will fail.

Comment: Very true twas a typo..name and names

Comment: 'name' is not present in CategoryForm Meta fields >>  fields = ('views', 'likes')